# Add an element to a jquery object

Tags: jquery

I've got a cached jquery object setup like this

```
var comments = $('li.comment');
```

When creating new elements, is there an easy way to update the **comments** objects instead of redfining it? I'm looking fot something like

```
comments += $('li.newcomment');
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$("li.comment").add("li.newcomment");
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was simple... :)